# Tosca's Rest API: What configuration is needed to execute Change and Create commands?

Tags: tosca

I've configured Tosca's REST API. All the endpoints are available. All read commands are executed successfully.

However, when trying to Post changes to an object or trying to execute a task to create a new object (regardless of type), the API returns with a 500 - Changes are not allowed to this object and 404 - Task not applicable error. Spelling errors would result in a 404 - Task not found error, so that can't be it. When providing a wrong object ID the API will also return a different error.

Also, I'm unable to change the checkout state of on object. The API returns the Request with a 200 - success message. However, the changes aren't propagated. Neither in the front-end, nor when reading the objects with the API.

I'm authenticated with an admin user. Is there some config that I've missed?

When trying to change an object I use the following POST endpoint:
`http://ServerIP/Rest/ToscaCommander/$MyWorkspace/object`
Providing the following payload:

```
{
   "Attributes": [
      "Name": "Name"
      "Value": "SomeNewName"
   ],
   "UniqueId": "$objectID"
}
```

When trying to create an object I use e.g. the following GET endpoint:
`http://ServerIP/Rest/ToscaCommander/$MyWorkspace/object/$objectID/task/CreateTestCase`

For the checkout I use the following GET endpoint:
`http://ServerIP/Rest/ToscaCommander/$MyWorkspace/object/$objectID/task/Checkout` (only successfull request)

Both the endpoints and the payload appear to be syntactically correct. Therefore, I assume that I missed some magical "readOnlyEnabled=False" config setting. Since the error messages only contain the error code and a one liner, I don't know what the issue is.